# JavaScript Closure question: why is the second call to outerFn creating a new instance of outerVar?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I have a JavaScript question. Let me quote from the book 'Learning jQuery', page 389-390. The question concerns Closures.

I don't understand why "the second call to outerFn() is not resetting the value of outerVar, but [is], rather, creating a new instance of outerVar, bound to the scope of the second function call.

What is it about JavaScript that would make this so? What do I need to know about JavaScript so that I could infer this for myself?

The rest of the email is the quotation from the book.

```
function outerFn() {
  var outerVar = 0;
  function innerFn() {
    outerVar++;
    $('#example-7').print('outerVar = ' + outerVar);
  }
  return innerFn;
}
var fnRef = outerFn();
fnRef();
fnRef();
var fnRef2 = outerFn();
fnRef2();
fnRef2();
```

Now our function calls have more interesting behavior:
     outerVar = 1
     outerVar = 2
     outerVar = 1
     outerVar = 2
We get a mix of the two earlier effects. The calls to innerFn() through each 
reference increment outerVar independently. Note that the second call to 
outerFn() is not resetting the value of outerVar, but rather creating a new 
instance of outerVar, bound to the scope of the second function call. The 
upshot of this is that after the above calls, another call to fnRef() will 
print the value 3, and a subsequent call to fnRef2() will also print 3. The 
two counters are completely separate.

Comment: Sounds like you got it pretty well figgurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be over thinking it.

As always, every time a call to `outerFn` is made, it will create a new `outerVar` variable for that particular invocation of the function -- it's part of it's local scope. Thus, any functions that are within the scope of the particular call to `outerFn` that are returned (or passed along somehow) will have continue to have access to that scope -- a closure.

Comment: Thanks. I was not clearly distinguishing between calls to the outer function vs calls to the inner function. Now I think I understand. outerVar persists in repeated invocations of fnRef because the garbage collector couldn't collect it after. cuz there's a reference to outerVar outside of outerFn. When the line "var fnRef = outerFn();" was executed, a reference to outerVar outside of outerFn was created. Making outerVar a free variable. And then, as you point out, when outerFn is invoked for the second time, of course a new context is constructed.

Comment: That's correct, as long you hold onto `fnRef`, the particular instance of `outerVar` will continue to exist and be accessible by `fnRef`. Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is the whole idea of [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29). As the firs paragraph of the above wiki link states:

*In computer science, a closure (also lexical closure, function closure or function value) is a function together with a referencing environment for the nonlocal names (free variables) of that function. Such a function is said to be "closed over" its free variables. The referencing environment binds the nonlocal names to the corresponding variables in scope at the time the closure is created, additionally extending their lifetime to at least as long as the lifetime of the closure itself.*

This behavior is not a particularity of javascript - it happens this way in every language that offer support for closures

Comment: Thanks. In the definition you quoted, I don't see any distinction between global variables and free variables. Both are nonlocal. Doesn't the definition of 'free variable' need to be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

outerVar is simply a local variable in the function outerFn.  Every invocation of outerFn creates a new set of local variables specific to that particular function call.

If you want outerVar to retain it's value from one invocation to another, then you need to define it in a scope outside of outerFn that survives between your function calls (it can be global or some other scope above the function level that survives).

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean "a scope outside of outerFn"?

Answer (score 0):

Without closure functions would be limited to using variables that are passed in as arguments.

To be able to make use of variables declared outside of the function those variables must be captured when the function is created. Each time the function is created it captures the complete set of variables that are currently in scope.

Comment: I don't see why closure must exist for functions to have access to variables defined outside themselves.

Comment: it is because of first class functions. A function can be passed to a completely different scope where closure becomes the only way to access the variables that were in scope when it was defined.